# Error while looping and displaying content

Tags: html, angular7, ngmodel

I have an array as below:

```
values = [
    {"name": "John","value":1},
    {"name": "Miller","value":2}
];
```

My DOM code

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor ="let finalvalue of values">
      <td width="55">{{finalvalue.name}}</td>
      <td width="55"><input type="text"[(ngModel)]="finalvalue.value"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Expected :

John 1
Miller 2

Actual :
John 2
Miller 2

Whatever is my final value it is getting shown across all the names on UI.
What could be the reason for this? How can I resolve it?

Here instead of `input` tag if I use a `label` and display the value then I am getting the result as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, sorry, wrong version of Angular in my first answer. Please see the following snippet that I cloned from another example that does what you're looking for: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcwxhe

Do you have the following imports/declarations declared, `FormsModule`, etc.:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: I think he is using another version of angular.

Comment: I have FormsModule imported in my application.
I have the above code inside a form tag
When I write the code outside of form tag it is working. Don't know why.....

My previous code will look like below
<form>
 <table>
  <tr *ngFor="let finalvalue of values">
   <td width="55">{{finalvalue.name}}</td>
   <td width="55"><input type="text" name="cardValue" [(ngModel)]="finalvalue.value"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

I tried this in stackblitz. It showed two 2 values.